# Grails 2.3 Error initializing the application: No bean named 'urlMappingsTargetSource' is defined

Tags: spring, grails, grails-2.3

I am using Grails 2.3.11.
In BootStrap.groovy I call:

```
def ctx = servletContext.getAttribute(ApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT)
HotSwappableTargetSource ts = ctx.getBean("urlMappingsTargetSource")
```

I am getting a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

```
12,09 21:55:44:084 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader - Error initializing the application: No bean named 'urlMappingsTargetSource' is defined
   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'urlMappingsTargetSource' is defined
   at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:10)
   at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:308)
   at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:301)
   at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:277)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

This does not throw an exception when I run the application in my development environment. However if I build a war file and deploy to tomcat I get a org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

This line worked okay when using Grails 2.1.0 and 2.2.4. I have also tried Grails 2.3.9 but this also throws a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.

I have also try using dependancy injection but "urlMappingsTargetSource" is null

```
class BootStrap {

    def urlMappingsTargetSource
```

Has anybody else come across this issue or does anybody know why I am getting a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException?

Has something changed the way this bean gets loaded in Grails 2.3 vs Grails 2.2 or 2.1?

Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Aren't you using some plugin? Is that `urlMappingsTargetSource` is the standard Grails ability?
Please look at the next links, looks like analogues.
https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10923
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663522/grails-error-creating-and-mapping-a-view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UrlMappingsGrailsPlugin.groovy contains the following code

```
    if (Environment.isDevelopmentMode() || Environment.current.isReloadEnabled()) {
        "org.grails.internal.URL_MAPPINGS_HOLDER"(UrlMappingsHolderFactoryBean) { bean ->
            bean.lazyInit = true
        }

        urlMappingsTargetSource(HotSwappableTargetSource, ref("org.grails.internal.URL_MAPPINGS_HOLDER")) { bean ->
            bean.lazyInit = true
        }

        grailsUrlMappingsHolder(ProxyFactoryBean) { bean ->
            bean.lazyInit = true
            targetSource = urlMappingsTargetSource
            proxyInterfaces = [UrlMappings]
        }
    } else {
        grailsUrlMappingsHolder(UrlMappingsHolderFactoryBean) { bean ->
            bean.lazyInit = true
        }
    }
```

If the envrionment is not development mode or reload enabled the beans do not get initialized.
I added the beans to my resources.groovy and it worked

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingsHolderFactoryBean
import org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean
import org.springframework.aop.target.HotSwappableTargetSource

// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
"org.grails.internal.URL_MAPPINGS_HOLDER"(UrlMappingsHolderFactoryBean) { bean ->
    bean.lazyInit = true
}

urlMappingsTargetSource(HotSwappableTargetSource, ref("org.grails.internal.URL_MAPPINGS_HOLDER")) { bean ->
    bean.lazyInit = true
}

grailsUrlMappingsHolder(ProxyFactoryBean) { bean ->
    bean.lazyInit = true
    targetSource = urlMappingsTargetSource
    proxyInterfaces = [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappings]
}
}
```